# Pass smarty variable into {php}

Tags: php, smarty

I need a fragment of code which will transfer a smarty object into a php variable.

```
<h1>{$box.heading}</h1>
```

I need to get the {$box.heading} value. Something like

```
{php}
$header = {$box.heading}
{/php}
```

Is that even possible? btw. it is a .tpl file

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [assign](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl)

```
{assign var=heading value=$box['heading']}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I've tried your answer, but when i do `echo $heading;`, I get an empty value, while the `<h1>{$box.heading}</h1>` returns a name of the product correctly. Did I do something wrong?   
`<h1>{$box.heading}</h1>

  {assign var=heading value=$box['heading']}

  {php}
  

  echo "product: " . $heading;

  {/php}`